# Evidence of firm borrowing and loans

Tags: macroeconomics, finance, reference-request, academic-graduate, corporate-finance

I'm absolutely not from firm financing and look to read up on the subject, but mostly onto empirical stuff.

Standard questions would be:

- What is the ratio of firms that finance themselves with bank loans?
- How does this vary with firm size?
- What's the duration of these loans?

Is there some handbook chapter or something similar for this?

Comment: From what I hear, corporations don't like to bank debt. http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/05/reasonforcorporatebonds.asp In the meantime, I'll look for data on this and hopefully a lit. review.

Comment: Yes, but stock market access comes with a fixed cost. My prior is that many (small) firms still depend on it, whether they like it or not.

Comment: Right. I think there's a big difference between how small and large firms finance themselves (small firms are more likely to take bank loans, I'm sure). But, this article doesn't talk as much about issuing stock ("stock market access") as much as issuing debt (corporate bonds versus bank debt).